# Eclipse's Ctrl+1 in IntelliJ and Android Studio

Tags: eclipse, android-studio, intellij-idea

I really like the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> shortcut (hints for errors and mini refactorings) in Eclipse. Is there an equivalent for it in IntelliJ and Android Studio?

Comment: Hints for error solving. The same as hovering an error with the mouse in intelliJ.

Comment: Not only for errors. You can use for extract variable, extract methods, inline variable, split string, invert conditions, etc... Very handy tool, essential for me.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: How do you make it work anywhere on the line? Ctrl+1 in Eclipse gives you suggestions for fixing problems anywhere on the line. When I do Alt+Enter in Idea at the end of the line, let's say after semicolon, then I will get no suggestions, resp. none that address the problem at the beginning of the line.

Comment: So I'm assuming no, it's not possible.

Comment: Alt+Enter is not the equivalent of Ctrl+1 in Eclipse.

Comment: @elron, it's not the direct equivalent, but it's the closest thing you can get.

Comment: It can be partially worked around by using F2 / Shift+F2 to jump to the next / previous highlighted error. This has two problems: 1) this shortcut is a bit cumbersome esp. combining it with Alt+Enter 2) it jumps to spelling mistakes, unused variables and methods, etc. too. 1) I solved by mapping Alt+[ / Alt+] for the jumping. I don't know if 2) can be adressed somehow too.

Comment: I think it works for the errors part (e.g. suggested fixes type thing), but it doesn't work for various other aspects of Ctrl-1. For those, the other answers help... there isn't a "smart all in one" that I've seen -- which is basically what ctrl-1 is. It's clear from the answers that people use Ctrl-1 for different things. :)

Answer (score 34):

Personally I don't think <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> is particularly correct.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> does lots of code generation like generating local variables given a method call etc.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> ... generates a local variable

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> ... generate a field

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd> ... generate (drop down menu to generate all sorts)

Now, unrelated to the question but maybe helpful and in the same ball park is that the "**foreach**" short cut in IntelliJ is <kbd>iter</kbd> rather than <kbd>for</kbd>.

Comment: @zirael - Yes I do like your answer. I think the thing is they are all correct in that CTRL - 1 does 3 sorts of things - Refactor, Generate code and Fix. Good that between all the answers we have all of those things covered.

Comment: The equivalent of `Alt + Insert` in Mac is: `Cmd + N`

Answer (score 14):

I also don't think ctrl+enter is the answer.

I'd say **<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>** (Refactor this...) which I remapped to <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is the closest thing to ctrl+1 from eclipse. It allows you to inline, extract code (variable, method, field etc.), move code, pull members etc.

Comment: I like this the most. On mac it's just ctrl+t.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> was one of my favorite shortcuts but unfortunately **there is no exact equivalent shortcut** for that. You can search for Quick fix in: `File-->Settings-->Keymap`, but you'll find nothing.

Although many people would say <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> is the nearest answer. but I think there are better equivalents such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. It will give you some magic options.

You can also remap it to  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> by going to:

`File-->Settings-->Keymap`

[image]

Comment: Looks exactly like my answer above mate ;)

Comment: @zirael although its similar to your answer I wanted to add some more explanation and cause I cant edit your answer I've added another answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>.

It will give the return type exactly of that method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the "Other -> Show Context Actions" is very close to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> in Eclipse.