# How to fake C++-style "auto" type deduction with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea

In some applications in Java, I am missing the "auto" keyword from C++. Don't get me wrong, this is absolutely not a discussion about language philosophies or programming practices.

If, for example I have a Map of Maps, and I want to have the associated entryset, the code looks like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, VeryLongClassNameGetsEvenLongerAndLonger>> map = new HashMap<>();

Set<Map.Entry<String, Map<String, VeryLongClassNameGetsEvenLongerAndLonger>>> entryset = map.entrySet();
```

Now the type the variable "entryset" is very awkward to type out and to get right. In C++, I would use auto here. That does not exist in Java, so I use the next best thing that is offered by the IntelliJ IDE. I type

```
Integer entryset = map.entrySet();
```

This is obviously incorrect, but this prompts IntelliJ to suggest to me:

```
Change variable 'entryset' type to 'Set<Map.Entry<String, Map<String, VeryLongClassNameGetsEvenLongerAndLonger>>>
```

So I just hit Alt-Enter and it is autocorrected.

However, I am wondering: can I do that without going through the correction-feature? Something like an "autocomplete type"-Hotkey, or a /auto/ pragma, or something?

Comment: Just use Kotlin, bro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You can type an expression and `.var` after it, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it will create a variable declaration
- You can write an expression and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> (by default), the expression will be extracted to a new variable.
- If you like C#/Scala/Kotlin style declarations with `var` and `val` keywords, you might find useful [Varsity](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7574?pr=) plugin.

  It lets you write variable declarations in the following way:

  ```
  var entrySet = map.entrySet();
  ```

  Then you hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and it becomes

  ```
  Set<Map.Entry<TheKeyType, TheValueType>> entrySet = map.entrySet();
  ```

Comment: The same result can be achieved without any plugins. Just input `map.entrySet()` and press `CTRL-ALT-V`. [More info](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16533971/758991).

Comment: @djxak, yeah, and even by just typing `.var` + `Tab` after an expression.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I like the first two options. Is there anything that I can use in a loop header, like `for (something entry : map.entrySet())` as well? I tried it and neither of those options works well in that case.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out that typeing `iter<tab>` does what I want to do, but better.

Answer (score 2):

Leave the type out.  Intellij will suggest creating a local variable, and will infer from the return type. E.g. type...

```
entryset = map.entrySet();
```

*entryset* will now be in red, signifying an error.

Then <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, which should display a small menu with *Create Local Variable* as an option.